# With Angular how to fill the canvas of a base component from a child component using template inheritance

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I have a base component with a canvas in it. I can fill the canvas a solid colour in the ngOnInit method of this base class.

I have a child component which inherits the template of the base. I try to call the base's canvas fill method from the child's ngAfterViewInit method but it says that the canvas element is null.

I have put in alert messages and they are coming up in the order I expect. The first is in the ngOnInit  method of the base and the second in the base's fillCanvas method which I call from the child's ngAfterViewInit method.

I have the code in StackBlitz here:

[Code Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezfnh1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.ts)

Can anyone help show me what I have done wrong \ need to do so as to be able to achieve filling of the canvas from the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need inheritance here, you can just call the function from the viewChild of that element, example below!

child

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from '../base/base.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(BaseComponent) base: BaseComponent;
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.base.fillCanvas();
  }
}
```

child html

```
<app-base [templateRef]="childTemplate"></app-base>

<ng-template #childTemplate> Child's extended template </ng-template>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ho59r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fbase%2Fbase.component.ts)